# NullReferenceException when using razor if statements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple details view that uses two if statements if the user is a `Customer`, it displays the customer properties. If the user is an `Investor` it displays their properties instead.

My issue is that my if statement works for one or the other but not both. Giving me a:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

when trying to use both if statements.

---

**My view**

```
@model MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser
<h3>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.FirstName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.LastName)
</h3>
@if (Model.Customer.CustomerId != null)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Tax ID:</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Customer.TaxId)
    </div>
} else {
}

@if (Model.Investor.InvestorId != null)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Social Security #:</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Investor.SsnNum)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <strong>Date of birth:</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Investor.DOB)
    </div>
} else {
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null || id.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var userFromDb = await _db.ApplicationUser.Include(u => u.Investor).Include(u => u.Customer).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
    if (userFromDb == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(userFromDb);
}
```

**Investor**

```
public class Investor
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string InvestorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "SSN")]
    public string SsnNum { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you populate `Customer` and `Investor`. I suspect one of them is not initialized hence you would get NULL reference error.

Comment: Instead of `if (Model.Customer.CustomerId != null)` have `if (Model.Customer != null && Model.Customer.CustomerId != null)`.

Comment: The view works with the if statement until I use both if statements then it throws an error. I can use the if statement for investor and it works or customer and it works, just not both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Because one or the other with *always* be null. It's either going to have a `Customer` or it's going to have an `Investor`, but never both. You should write your conditionals like `Model.Customer != null && Model.Customer.CustomerId != null` like @WiktorZychla suggested. You can also use the null conditional operator like `Model.Customer?.CustomerId != null`, which is a little easier.

Comment: Thanks, I was just thinking that before I saw your comment and the code you provided fixed the issue

Comment: @ChrisPratt why not `Model.Customer?.CustomerId != null` :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Looks like what I had already to my eyes. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes.. you're missing the fact that I didn't read lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are trying to access a property of `Customer` or `Investor` which is not initialized. First of all check, that weather `Customer` or `Investor` is null or not then check for its properties.

```
@model MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser
<h3>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.FirstName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.LastName)
</h3>
@if (Model.Customer?.CustomerId != null)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Tax ID:</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Customer.TaxId)
    </div>
} else {
}

@if (Model.Investor?.InvestorId != null)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Social Security #:</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Investor.SsnNum)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <strong>Date of birth:</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Investor.DOB)
    </div>
} else {
}
```

Comment: You logic can be shortened to `Model.Custromer?.CustomerId != null` and `Model.Investor?.InvestorId != null`.

Comment: @Erik Philips yes, But I didn't know which version of C# he is using. Definitely, If he is using C# 5.0 or above then can use it.

Comment: Consider the `Details` method, it is using async/await only came out in c# 5.0 :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yeh sure, I didn't consider that. Thanks!